# Is there a shared encrypt / decrypt methods between java and c#?

Tags: java, c#, cryptography

I'm developing a mobile app in android studio and on the other side have an API in c# language.
Some text data should encrypt on the API and send it to the Mobile app and it should decrypt it.

Is it possible?

If yes what kind of encryption/decryption methods should I use who both Java and c# can work with it to pass data between themself?

Comment: Cryptographic functions are mathematical functions, not java functions or c# function. Any cryptographic algorithm you can implement in java can be implemented in C# and vice versa.

Comment: The most common pitfall is that some ciphers have different defaults for mode and/or padding on Java and C#. So, be very explicit with specifying your cipher and you should be fine for a ton of ciphers.

Comment: Use a secure channel like TLS with no need for encryption OR use a Key Exchange protocol ('Diffie Hellman').

Comment: @MichaelFehr I think you mean that there is no need to implement the encryption or key exchange yourself if you use TLS from 3rd party libs ... but if you write 'no need for encryption OR use a Key Exchange protocol ('Diffie Hellman')' it kind of saying 'who needs generators? our power comes from a wall socket...'

Comment: DarkSquirrel42's comment is easy to overlook if you don't know what TLS is.  TLS is exactly a protocol by which a client and server negotiate to find a common set of ciphers they both support, and then to establish (and maintain) a secure channel, taking care of all the key generation, and using certificates for proof of identity if you supply them.  Most modern languages with built-in crypto can run TLS.